# Shannon entropy of data in this format (DNA motif)?

Tags: python, format, bioinformatics, python-2.6, entropy

I have "DNA motifs" represented by position-weight-matrices (PWMs) a.k.a position-specific scoring matrices (PSSMs), in transfac format:

**transfac format**:

- Motif names are shown in rows following "DE"
- Each numbered row represents the observed frequencies of four possible DNA bases ("letters"): A, G, T and C, at a given position along the whole DNA motif sequence (these positions are shown by the first column)
- Row 0 is the first letter along the DNA motif sequence, and the row before "XX" is the final position along the DNA motif sequence
- The righter-most column shows the most representative letter for that position along the sequence, based on the observed frequencies; these can be given ambiguity codes (not A,G,C,T) if no particular letter is representative
- finally "XX" delimits multiple DNA motifs

**E.g.** SRF: GCCCATATATGGGTTGTNNTC, and HMG-1: GTTGNNTC

```
DE    SRF
0    0.0435    0.0217    0.8478    0.0870    G
1    0.1957    0.7174    0.0435    0.0435    C
2    0.0000    0.9782    0.0217    0.0000    C
3    0.0217    0.9782    0.0000    0.0000    C
4    0.6956    0.0217    0.0000    0.2826    A
5    0.0652    0.0217    0.0000    0.9130    T
6    1.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    A
7    0.0217    0.0000    0.0000    0.9782    T
8    0.9348    0.0000    0.0000    0.0652    A
9    0.3261    0.0217    0.0000    0.6522    T
10    0.0435    0.0000    0.9565    0.0000    G
11    0.0435    0.0217    0.9348    0.0000    G
XX
DE    HMG-1
0    0.0000    0.3846    0.6154    0.0000    G
1    0.0000    0.0000    0.2308    0.7692    T
2    0.0000    0.3077    0.0000    0.6923    T
3    0.0000    0.1539    0.7692    0.0769    G
4    0.0000    0.0769    0.0000    0.9230    T
5    0.4615    0.0769    0.2308    0.2308    N
6    0.2308    0.3846    0.0000    0.3846    N
7    0.0000    0.0769    0.1539    0.7692    T
8    0.0000    0.6154    0.0769    0.3077    C
XX
```

**Question**: How can I calculate the Shannon Entropy for each DNA motif in Python? Are there any Python packages out there for data like this (I don't know the non-biological jargon for these data structures)?, or perhaps somebody can provide a neat Python function?

Comment: Have you found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577476-shannon-entropy-calculation/) recipe?

Comment: [This](http://pythonfiddle.com/shannon-entropy-calculation/) python fiddle might also be useful.

Comment: cheers for the help @creimers but i did see those before and neither are appropriate i'm afraid :( ~the format of my data is less "raw" than a string of letters... it already has the observed decimal frequencies for each letter along the string and the alphabet is strictly confined to AGCT

Comment: @hello_there_andy if neither of them are appropriate maybe you are unable to adopt them to your specific task. Please show us the problems you have with modifying the code to fit your needs. Then I will think about helping you. Both results show how to compute the Shannon entropy.

Answer (score 2):

There is a caveat related to the comments (see below), but I came up with a little code that handles the text file you gave:

```
import numpy as np
import sys

def compute_entropy(motif):
    arr = np.array(motif)
    H = (arr[arr > 0] * np.log2(arr[arr > 0])).sum(axis=1)
    print 'entropy:', -H.mean(), 'bits'

motif = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip().lower()
    if line.startswith('de'):
        print line
    elif line == 'xx':
        if motif:
            compute_entropy(motif)
        motif = []
    else:
        motif.append(map(float, line.split()[1:-1]))
```

The caveat is that it's unclear which is the right way to define entropy for a sequence of multivariate values drawn from different distributions---or, at least, there are several ways to do it, and each has a different underlying statistical model.

I assume the bioinformatics folks have decided on a right way, but the way I did it is to treat each letter in the sequence as being an independent draw from a multinomial at that sequence position, and then I average the entropy for each of those draws.

You could probably argue that you need to sum the individual entropy values (or any number of other ways to combine them), so that decision is up to you.

Comment: nice! your assumption is in line with (most) biologists :) ~but we're aware it haunts us... thank you so much for that @lmjohns3

Comment: Hi @lmjohns3, by the way, there's an error I get with your "compute_entropy()" function: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: axis(=1) out of bounds` because in the function you have sum(axis=1) I changed this to axis=0 but that's probably wrong?

Comment: The `compute_entropy` function needs to be passed a list of lists, i.e., a two-dimensional array of numbers. The code below the function parses a list of lists out of the example input that you provided, if you supply the input on stdin. Try saving the code in a file called `entropy.py` and then run it using: `cat my-gene-data.txt | python entropy.py` (on linux or mac).

Answer (score 0):

here's a bit of background noise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPLGN0yIDTg

Basically the biology models and the code are too far apart to really do much just yet. Meaningful genetic code is, needs useful machine apparition to get us over the babylon.

Multivariate values can be compressed somehow. What we are aiming for is a recursive machine picture of reality with enough fractal truth to uphold our worldly things.